# What are the available Native renderrers for Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, native

I understood that even though Angular 2 is a complete ecosystem, it does not provide any Native renderrer , instead you can plugin any library like Ionic for Native rendering.

***are there any other alternative ?***

Comment: For creating Mobile apps? You can use NativeScript or ReactNative with Angular2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Angular does feature a Renderer class but its listed as experimental: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html